# Incorrect OS Name: Microsoft**r** Windows Server**r**?

Tags: windows

I bought a Windows VPS. Computer property page doesn't show the version of Windows.

[image]

I run `systeminfo > output.txt` and output.txt says

```
Host Name:                 WIN-HSSEHB0RKBD
OS Name:                   Microsoftr Windows Serverr 2008 Standard 
OS Version:                6.0.6002 Service Pack 2 Build 6002
OS Manufacturer:           Microsoft Corporation
OS Configuration:          Standalone Server
OS Build Type:             Multiprocessor Free
Registered Owner:          Windows User
```

**Note the very weird OS Name, one more r after Microsoft and one more r after Server.**

I go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion. Fields there seem to be correct.

[image]

Can I fix OS Name to the correct string? Is it possible to set OS name to any arbitary string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are seeing is an error in character reproduction. The extra *r* is the registered trademark symbol ®, but it did not translate properly when converted to text form in the registry, either by software means or due to lazy retyping by some programmer. This means that this is effectively what it was supposed to show: Microsoft® Windows Server® 2008 Standard.

I would not change it just in case programs you use ever check that value.

Comment: Will this issue prevent me from installing certain software? For example a program is supposed to run on "Microsoft Windows Server 2008 Standard" but the string it get from API is "Microsoft**r** Windows Server**r** 2008 Standard"?

Comment: I would bet that since it is an issue across an entire platform that it would not be a problem. It is not just there in your copy. Microsoft would most certainly be aware of this, maybe even programmed it to be that way to differentiate it between other similar versions. That sort of thing happens all the time under the hood.

Comment: Sample tech article from a while back illustrates the point of extra "r"s in the name: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1245848&seqNum=4